# Is this function bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis

Is the function below bounded variation over [0,1]? Why? What is V(f,[0,1])?
$$F(x)=\begin{cases} (\sqrt{x} sin(\frac{1}{x}) &, x\ne0 \\0 &, x=0 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. Intuitively, if you graph this, you will see there are infinitely many ups and downs near $0$ and the sum of the lengths is not convergent (see for yourself: the graph bounces infinitely many times between $y=\sqrt{x}, y=-\sqrt{x}$).

Rigorously, solve for $\sin(1/x)=1$, thus $1/x=2k\pi+\pi/2$ and solve for $\sin(1/x)=-1$, thus $1/x=2k\pi+3\pi/2$. Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$. The variation of $F$ is greater than the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^N|F(\frac{1}{2n\pi+\pi/2})-F(\frac{1}{2n\pi+3\pi/2)})|.$$
(why: take any partition of $[0,1]$ that contains these points. Then the total variation is greater than $\sum|F(x)-F(x')|$ where $x,x'$ are consequent points of the partition. Now the sum where $x,x'$ range only over these specific points is obviously a smallar quantity.)

These terms we are adding are $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\pi+\pi/2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\pi+3\pi/2}}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$
so the total variation is greater than $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{(2\pi n)^{1/2}}$ for all $N$. But this series diverges.